# std::array to pointer access violation error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make my Transpose function take pointers instead of `std::arrays`. And the reason I want to do this is because then I can pass it a pointer or `std::array` via the `.data()` function.

Currently I have the following and it works using both 2D and 1D arrays for transposing in place or to a new array.. However, converting the below code to take pointers instead gives a memory access violation error.

Can someone explain the difference and why the below is not equal to my pointer versions (below this):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
void Transpose(std::array<T, Size> &Data)
{
    int Width = sqrt(Size);
    for (int I = 1; I < Width; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I * Width + J], Data[J * Width + I]);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
void Transpose(std::array<std::array<T, Size>, Size> &Data)
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I][J], Data[J][I]);
        }
    }
}
```

However converting to the below does not work when I use a pointer :S

```
template<typename T>
void Transpose(T* Data, std::size_t Size)
{
    int Width = sqrt(Size);
    for (int I = 1; I < Width; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I * Width + J], Data[J * Width + I]);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Transpose(T** Data, std::size_t Size)
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I][J], Data[J][I]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain the difference and why the `T**` one does not work?

Comment: In what way is it not equal (besides the double pointer)? Are you getting different outputs, errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two-dimensional array doesn't decay into a double pointer. It decays into `T*[]`. For an explanation, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183546/why-does-int-decay-into-int-but-not-int).

You'll have to change the faulty line to:

```
void Transpose(T* Data[], std::size_t Size)
```

or (so the length can be deduced)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size1, std::size_t Size2>
void Transpose(T (&Data)[Size1][Size2])
```