# T*[] vs T** function declaration

Tags: c++

I was told there actually is a difference between a `T*[] and a T**` and that a two dimensional array does not decay into T** as shown here: [std::array to pointer access violation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012382/stdarray-to-pointer-access-violation-error)

However.. If they are not the same, then why can't I declare BOTH of these functions?

```
template<typename T>
void Transpose(T** Data, std::size_t Size)
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I][J], Data[J][I]);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Transpose(T* Data[], std::size_t Size)
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I][J], Data[J][I]);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says that its already declared.. Any ideas?

Comment: They are the same in this context.

Comment: `T* t[]` is syntactic sugar for `T** t` when used as function parameters.

Comment: So then `int**` and `int[][]` is the same because each `*` is a `[]`?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: No, because (a) `int[][]` is not legal C++, and (b) the array-to-pointer decay only occurs at the top level.

Comment: I don't understand :S  if I do:  `int Foo[2][2]`.  and `int** Foo = new int[2]` `Foo[I] = new int[2];`

Why are they different if a `*` is a `[]` according to that function definition?

Answer (score 2):

It's because in function argument lists, `T* data[]` is just another way to write `T** data`.

To distinguish between arrays and pointers, you can do the following:

```
template<typemane T> void Transpose(T** data, ...) { ... }

template<typename T, int N> void Transpose(T* (&data)[N], ...) { ... }
```

However in your case, you don't not use that distinction anyway, so you can just write the first version and omit the second. The automatic decay of array to pointer when calling the function will make it work on arrays as well.

Answer (score 1):

T*[] and T** are the same when they're used as function parameters.