# Writing array reference using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays

let consider the following fragment of Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int count[100][10];
 *(count + (44*10)+8)=99;
 printf("%d",count[44][8]);
}
```

What is the wrong with it?

Comment: Not an answer: Using `int main()` would be nice

Comment: `count[44][8]= 99` .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does int\*\[\] decay into int\*\* but not int\[\]\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183546/why-does-int-decay-into-int-but-not-int)

Answer (score 2):

```
count[44][8]
```

is not initialized and you are trying to print the value of it which is UB.

```
a[i][j] = *(a[i] + j); 
a[i][j] = *(*(a+i) + j);
```

So if you want to initialize `count[44][8]` then do

```
*(count[44] + 8) = 10; /* or *(*(count + 44) + 8) = 10 */
printf("%d",count[44][8]);
```

Comment: Would U please explain ur code...! is it a rule a[i][j] = *(a[i] + j); 
a[i][j] = *(*(a+i) + j) for accessing 2d array @Gopi

Comment: int count[100][10],*countP;
 countP=count;
 *(countP[44]+8)=99; it is not working for this fragment.

Comment: @BlackSwan - that is the rule. Any array is simply a block of addresses in memory. You can address any specific address with either normal array notation `count[44][8]` or by specifying the `offset` in memory from the base address of count (e.g. `*(*(count + 44) + 8)`). The basic equivalence is easier understood for a 1D array: `a[i] = *(a + i)`. For a 2D array, you simply have an additional layer: `a[i][j] = *(*(a + i) + j)`

Answer (score 2):

Array-to-pointer decay only works for one level; so `int count[100][10];` decays to `int (*)[100]` ([Why does int*[] decay into int** but not int[][]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183546/why-does-int-decay-into-int-but-not-int)).

You can either cast `count` to `int*` or use `&count[0][0]` to get an `int*` pointer to the first element of the 2D array.

Comment: i am not familiar c++, only with C. it worked in ur way, but i am still confused that why i have to cast it...!

Comment: @BlackSwan see Oliver Charlesworth's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14183554/567292 - array-to-pointer decay works exactly the same in C and C++, it's just that C++ gives more ways to observe it.

Answer (score 1):

`*(count + (44*10)+8)=99;` should be

```
*(count[0] + (44*10)+8)=99;
```

Type of `countp[0]` can be reinterpreted as `int *` as you want.

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/8POTAO)

Type of `count` is `int [100][10]` so adding some big number to it would go 10 times ahead as you want and access to that location would lead to UB.

Anopter way to write the same is:

```
*( *(count + 44) + 8 )=99;
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: @EdHeal I accidentally hit some key + enter key which submitted answer before completion. I accept (+1 for reminding) it was incomplete.

Comment: is ur answer complete now? @Mohit Jain

Comment: @BlackSwan Yes, it complete now.