# Relationship between int[n][n] and int**

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I have a constructor for my class Graph:

```
template <typename T>
Graph<T>::Graph(T ** input)
{
    graphData = input;
}
```

When I tried to crate a new instance of this class using a two dimensional array instead of int**

```
int intArray[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
Graph<int>* IntGraph = new Graph<int>(intArray);
```

I've got an error `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [3][3]' to 'int **`

I'm new to c++ and I thought that these types are compatible. Can you please describe me the difference?

EDIT:
since this question was marked as a duplicate, I also wanted to ask, what is the best way to convert one of these types into another, or what to use instead without any loss of performance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183546/why-does-int-decay-into-int-but-not-int

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the difference. However, I didn't found the way, how to transform one into another.

Comment: What you're trying to do here looks dangerous and complicated. I can see undefined behaviour coming from someone passing a pointer to a local object into the constructor. Do yourself a favour and use a `std::vector` inside `Graph`.

Comment: A held question is a particularly bad place to append a second question. You probably want to make a new question.

Comment: I would love to, but the system dosn't allow me to ask another question for another 3 days. I'm trying my best to ask the questions the right way, but as I can see, this server is not beginner friendly.

Comment: If you have a question, please make a new post, don't edit it into this question. The restriction for 3 days is there for a reason, please don't try to go around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int [3][3]` is converted in expressions with rare exceptions (for example when used in the sizeof operator) to `int ( * )[3]`.

`int ( * )[3]` is pointer to an array of type `int[3]` While `int **` is pointer to an object of type `int *`

Consider the following example

```
int a[3][3];
int ( *pa )[3] = a;

int * b[3];
int **pb = b;
```

Or the last declaration you can write like

```
int * ( *pb ) = b;
```

In this example pointer `pa` is initialized with the address of the first element of two-dimensional array `a`. Elements of a two-dimensional array are one-dimensional arrays.

Pointer `pb` is also initialized by the address of the first element in this case of array `b`. Elements of the array are objects of type `int *`.

You can not convert one of these types into another.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert int[][] to int** because int[][] is a continuous block of memory in your case of size 2*3, while int** expects a pointer to a pointer to an int.

AFIK. you can do:

```
void myfunc(int myarray[][3]);
```